# FreePBX call recording - increase volume on one stream

Tags: asterisk, freepbx

I have a FreePBX installation and have set the Call Recording options on both the Inbound and Outbound Routes to Yes.

Call recording is happening for both inbound and outbound calls but the inbound stream is so quiet that it's inaudible.

Is there a way to increase the volume of just a single stream.

I am aware of the tx and rx gain commands but those change the volume for everything and we have no problem hearing callers during any calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After recording process done, you can execute script(see general settings in freepbx).

In that script you can use sox or any other convertor and increase gain on one channel. Asterisk save caller+called as left/right channel in mixed call.

Answer (score 2):

The MixMonitor command also has tx/rx gain settings, that only affect the volume of the recording, not the call itself. I don't know if these parameters are available on the FreePBX GUI or not.

```
asterisk*CLI> core show application MixMonitor
v(x): Adjust the *heard* volume by a factor of <x> (range '-4' to '4')
V(x): Adjust the *spoken* volume by a factor of <x> (range '-4' to '4')
W(x): Adjust both, *heard and spoken* volumes by a factor of <x> (range '-4' to '4')
```

Alternatively, you can record the received and transmitted streams separately.

```
r(file): Use the specified file to record the *receive* audio feed. Like with the basic filename argument, if an absolute path isn't given, it will create the file in the configured monitoring directory.
t(file): Use the specified file to record the *transmit* audio feed. Like with the basic filename argument, if an absolute path isn't given, it will create the file in the configured monitoring directory.
```